# Mapbox basemap is getting blurred

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I want to use my custom created mapbox basemap in OpenLayers application,  I have added it at TileLayer with XYZ source, but the quality is getting blurred
[image]

This is the image from application

[image: this]

This is how it looks in Mapbox Studio.

My code

```
new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url:  'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/johnculturemee/cknzq8w4c4yq617jgv5kwg9tm/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=<my_key>',
          }),
        })
```

What might be the reason?

Comment: Looks like you've picked a scale between the ones that tiles are available for - Its hard to be sure with out seeing your code

Comment: Hi , 

 new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url:
              'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/johnculturemee/cknzq8w4c4yq617jgv5kwg9tm/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=<api_key>,
          }),
        }),

This is my layer

Comment: Post the rest of your code. Much easier to figure out when what you are doing can be seen. Easier to find an error in code than guess at the myriad things that can be wrong. Can your map be seen online?

Comment: Hi 
 new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url:
              'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/johnculturemee/cknzq8w4c4yq617jgv5kwg9tm/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=<my_key>',
          }),
        })

This is my layer. I'm able to see the basemap but it is blurred